# Laravel 5 downloading file

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to download a file using this function, but is not working and I am not getting any error.

```
 public function downloadSingleFile($id )
    {
       $file = Upload::find($id);
       $pathToFile = public_path() . '/uploads/' . $file->file_name; 
       return response()->download($pathToFile, $file->file_name);
    }
```

---

```
Route::get('dashboard/download_file/{id}', 'DashboardController@downloadFile');
```

Comment: Take a look at the log file in `storage/logs` and see if you can find an error.

Comment: I just checked and it doesn't show any error. I just checked and it doesn't show any error. The template is just blank page

Comment: Your route references `downloadFile` and the real method is called `downloadSingleFile`. Just a typo in the question?

Comment: Got it works. I was using an Interface for the download but apparently didn't like it. I moved the return response()->download($pathToFile, $file->file_name); in the Controller and it worked. Thanks anyway @lukasgeiter.